# Proof Verification: If $w_1,...,w_k\in V$ in linear independent, then so is $[w_1]_B,...,[w_k]_B$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, coordinate-systems

Question:

Let $B=\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ be the basis of vector space $V$. Prove that
if $w_1,...,w_k\in V$ are linear independent, then so are $[w_1]_B,...,[w_k]_B$.

Preliminaries:

1. According to the definition of linear dependence, a group of $n$ vectors are linearly dependent if $\exists \alpha_1,...\alpha_n|\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_nv_n=0$
2. According to the definition of coordinate spaces,
   $[w]_B=\left( \begin{array} cc_1\\...\\c_n \end{array} \right)$ such that $w=c_1b_1+...+c_nb_n$.

My Proof:

Proof by negation:

1. If $w_1,...,w_k\in V$ are linearly independent: $\forall\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k:\alpha_1(c_{1,1}b_1+...+c_{1,n}b_n)+...+\alpha_k(c_{k,1}b_1+...+c_{k.n}b_n)\ne0$
   Moved around a bit to form:
   $\forall\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k:b_1(\alpha_1c_{1,1}+...+\alpha_kc_{k,1})+...+b_n(\alpha_1c_{1,n}+...+\alpha_kc_{k,n})\ne0$
2. Let $[w_1]_B,...,[w_k]_B$ be linearly dependent: $\exists\beta_1,...,\beta_k:\beta_1\left( \begin{array} cc_{1,1}\\...\\c_{1,n} \end{array} \right)+...+\beta_k\left( \begin{array} cc_{k,1}\\...\\c_{k,n} \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array} c0\\...\\0 \end{array} \right)$
   Which tells us:
   $\begin{cases}\beta_1c_{1,1}+...+\beta_kc_{k,1}=0\\\beta_1c_{1,n}+...+\beta_kc_{k,n}=0\end{cases}$
3. Let $\forall1\le i\le k:\alpha_i=\beta_i$ causing (1) to become $b_1(0)+...+b(0)=0\ne0$ ('$...$' can be ignored in this case.) which is a contradiction$\blacksquare$

Comment: I would say a group of n vectors $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ are linearly independent iff $\lambda_1v_1+...+\lambda_nv_n=0\implies \lambda_1=....=\lambda_n=0$

Comment: Your proof should contain more explanation in words and less logical symbols. I don't understand your proof but if $w_1, \dots, w_k$ are linearly independent then for all $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_k$ we have that if $\alpha_1 w_1 + \dots + \alpha_k w_k = 0$ then $\alpha_1 = \dots = \alpha_k = 0$ which is not what you wrote. In addition, if you expand (say) $w_1$ in terms of the basis $b_1,\dots,b_n$, there is no reason it will have only $k$ coefficients - the correct equation is $w_1 = c_{1,1} b_1 + \dots + c_{1,n} b_n$ and not $b_k$.

Comment: @levap Correct me if I missed something, but your definition of linear independence is actually the definition for linear dependence. Maybe there was a typo? in terms of $b_n$ instead of $b_k$, that was a typo. I'll fix it right away!

Comment: @CluelessButCurious: Hmm. A collection of vectors is linearly independent if any linear combination of them which sums to zero is the trivial combination (all coefficients are zero). If you want to prove your claim by contradiction, you are given that $w_1,\dots,w_k$ are linearly independent and you assume by contradiction that $[w_1]_{B}, \dots, [w_k]_{B}$ are linearly dependent. I thought that in part $(1)$ you just wrote again what it means that $w_1,\dots,w_k$ are linearly independent and that you wrote it wrong but I can't really say what you had in mind.

Comment: @CluelessButCurious: Alternatively, you could have written that if some $\alpha_i$ is not zero then $\alpha_1 w_1 + \dots + \alpha_k w_k \neq 0$ which is an equivalent way of saying that $w_1,\dots,w_k$ are linearly independent.

Comment: BTW, an easier way in my opinion to prove your result is to use the fact that the linear map $T \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$ given by $v \mapsto [v]_{B}$ is an isomorphism and then deduce that $w_1,\dots,w_k$ are linearly independent in $V$ iff $Tw_1, \dots, Tw_k$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{F}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues you have in your proof. One is that you are very cavalier with regards to when things are zero or not. For instance, in $1)$ you should say that at least one of the $\alpha_i$ is not zero. Similarly at least one of the $\beta_i$ must be non-zero.

One glaring problem is your final line when you say "If $\alpha_i = \frac{\beta_i}{b_i}$". This is a huge problem because $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are scalars and $b_i$ is a vector!

---

I will present a very straightforward proof that avoids all those pesky subscripts. Let $\tilde{B}$ denote the matrix whose columns are the $b_i$. You can reinterpret the second statement in your preliminaries as $$ w = \tilde{B}[w]_B.$$

Suppose we have scalars $\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_k$ such that $\gamma_1[w_1]_B + \dots + \gamma_k[w_k]_B = 0$. Then:

\begin{align*}
0 &= \tilde{B}0 \\
&=\tilde{B}\left(\gamma_1[w_1]_B + \dots + \gamma_k[w_k]_B\right)\\
&=\gamma_1(\tilde{B}[w_1]_B) + \dots + \gamma_k(\tilde{B}[w_k]_B) \\
&=\gamma_1w_1 + \dots \gamma_k w_k.
\end{align*}

Because $w_1,\dots,w_k$ are linearly independent, we must have that $\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_k = 0$. Therefore $[w_1]_B,\dots,[w_k]_B$ are linearly independent.

---

As a side note: We didn't even need to use the fact that $\tilde{B}$ is invertible. Any linear transformation will map dependencies to dependencies. So in this case, if there was a linear dependence among the $[w_i]_B$'s, that would map to a linear dependence among the $w_i$'s which we know does not exist.

Comment: I actually just fixed the problem with the final line right before I saw this. If I were be more clear about when things are zero or not, would the proof be correct now?

Comment: The proof would be correct then. As a side note, you can use "\vdots" to get vertical dots $ \ \vdots \ $, which will look better in your vectors. Also, in the equations following the line "Which tells us:", I would add a "\vdots" as a middle line to indicate that there are actually a whole bunch of equations that we got there.